# Sonar JIRA Plugin: "Link to JIRA" is missing

Tags: jira, sonarqube

After installing the [Sonar JIRA plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Jira+Plugin) and restarting the Sonar server, I have run an analysis with the following properties configured in the Sonar Ant task:

- sonar.jira.url (no HTTPS used)
- sonar.jira.login.secured
- sonar.jira.password.secured
- sonar.jira.url.param (a JIRA filter)
- sonar.jira.project.key (the project key that is also used as prefix in JIRA issue keys)

The JIRA widget shows results for the configured JIRA filter, but the item "Link to JIRA" is missing from the "More actions" pop-up menu. I have tried this with Sonar 3.0, 3.4.1 and 3.5.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be able to link issues to JIRA, then you must specify all your properties in Sonar Web UI, not in your Ant build script.

Indeed, properties set on project files (may they be POM / sonar-project.properties / build.xml files) are not stored in the DB, so the UI can't retrieve this information and therefore won't display the link.

Comment: Thank you! I had to set sonar.jira.project.key in the project settings.

Comment: where to the find the project settings

Comment: Connect as Administrator to Sonar and click to Settings (top right corner) and click to Jira. You have to have Jira plugin installed for this. You can also browse /settings?category=jira

Answer (score 2):

On the dashboards, click into a project, on the right up corner, there is a Configuration dropdown menu, on the setting opiton, you can find the JIRA setting. there you will be able to see the JIRA project key input box.